# why nested If statement doesn't return data frame r?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

the nested if statement in this code is working very fine

```
x <- 4
if(x == 4){
  t <- x + 1
  if(t == 5){
   t + 2
 }
}
[1] 7
```

but when i try the same code on data frame there is no results.

```
mydata_one <- data.frame(words = c("hello", "everyone"))
mydata_two <- data.frame(words = c("my", "name"))
if(length(mydata_one$word) == 2){
  big_data <- rbind(mydata_one, mydata_two)
  if(length(big_data) > 3){
    big_data[1:3, 1]
   }
}
```

The expected value i am looking for:

```
[1] hello    everyone my
```

Comment: a data frame is just a special list. you haven't changed the # of columns so your (devoid of useful whitespace) `if (length(big_data) > 3) {` is still `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Length will not work with data frame. Use nrow instead to get number of records.

```
mydata_one <- data.frame(words = c("hello", "everyone"))
mydata_two <- data.frame(words = c("my", "name"))
if(length(mydata_one$word) == 2){
  big_data <- rbind(mydata_one, mydata_two)
  if(nrow(big_data) > 3){
    big_data[1:3, 1]
   }
}
```

**Output:**
[1] hello    everyone my
Levels: everyone hello my name